# Load Balancing using nginx , fail over network issue

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, high-availability

I am using **nginx** for my application load balancing. I have defined a cluster as

```
    upstream app_cluster {
        server 123.101.10.15:8080;      # Node.js instance 1
        server 123.101.10.16:8080 backup;      # Node.js instance 2
   }
```

I am doing a network fail over testing. Lets say, I am pulling the LAN cable of 
**123.101.10.15**  system.

I am getting 403 while accessing the application using nginx IPs.
And my request are not penetrating to 123.101.10.16 .

All the request are getting failed.

Can anybody help me on this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you try to access `http://123.101.10.16:8080` directly? I suspect that you'll receive a 403 error. If this is the case, ensure that NGINX has the necessary permissions to access Node.js. Your load balancing (failover) config is fine.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence : Even the http://123.101.10.16:8080 is also giving 403.

Comment: Okay, that's good. Now we know that the problem lies with your second server. This is a permissions issue. Look at the directory and file permissions, along with ownership, of your Node app on the first server and replicate that on your second server. Depending on the environment, NGINX might be running as a different user on server 16 than on server 15, so make sure you take this into account.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence : Once LAN is up, I could access the 2nd node as well.I don't know , how it behaves.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence : Once LAN is up, I could access both the node directly as well as I could access the application using nginx IP address

Comment: Ah, I see... Glad you got it sorted